# How to reference resource in terraform, using variables or counters (i.e. with range)?

Tags: terraform

I have a lot of similar (but a little bit different) virtual machine resources in my manifests, which have similar naming, i.e. `vcd_vapp_vm.worker_1_k8s, vcd_vapp_vm.worker_2_k8s, ..., vcd_vapp_vm.worker_100_k8s,` and i want to reference all or some of them in my load  balancer configuration. Right now i do it by declaring k8s_workers variable, like

```
k8s_workers = [
  vcd_vapp_vm.worker_1_k8s,
  vcd_vapp_vm.worker_2_k8s,
  vcd_vapp_vm.worker_3_k8s,
  vcd_vapp_vm.worker_4_k8s,
  # a lot of other workers
  vcd_vapp_vm.worker_100_k8s,
]
```

and referencing it inside LB configuration with dynamic block

```
  dynamic "member" {
    for_each = local.k8s_workers
    content {
      name         = member.value.computer_name
      ip_address   = member.value.network.0.ip
      # skipped other parameters
    }
  }
```

I'd like to reduce copypasting resources in array definition by using something like

```
k8s_workers = formatlist("vcd_vapp_vm.worker_%s_k8s", range(1, 100))
```

but to get actual resource reference instead of strings. Is there a way to achieve it in terraform?

I can work around that in this specific case with generating hostnames as strings as specified above and using `dns_a_record_set` to resolve hostnames that i need on "client side" to pass IPs to LB, but that's not the same thing as pulling data from state itself. I can't seem to find a correct syntax to do that

Comment: In theory, this could have been done using either `count` or `for_each` meta-arguments. That way you could avoid creating 100 resources of the same type which need to have different names. However, details are lacking, so it's hard to tell.

Comment: @MarkoE comment is root cause answer to question although not literal answer to question, but in this situation should be pursued as it probably solves other related issues.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like this idea in overall (don't understand why you need all these different resources instead one resource per instance type with count inside), but what about to pass:

```
k8s_workers = formatlist("vcd_vapp_vm.worker_%s_k8s", range(1, 100))
```

to `data` [resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/instance) as filter and then reference to this data to obtain information you need about each of them.

Comment: This seems like an aws-specific solution, which won't work for majority of other providers

Comment: Yah, sorry, always forgot that there is something else behind AWS exists :)